# Msal.UserAgentApplication don't call callback method in msal.js

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I used msal.js file (version 1.0.3) but the authCallback function is not get called,

var clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientID, applicationConfig.authority, authCallback, { cacheLocation: 'localStorage' });

```
    function authCallback(errorDesc, token, error, tokenType) {
        if (errorDesc != null && errorDesc.indexOf("AADB2C90118") > -1) {
            clientApplication.authority = applicationConfig.passwordAuthority;
        }
        login();
        var user = window.clientApplication.getUser();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the clientApplication object instantiated with Msal.js to make an interactive call like loginRedirect or loginPopup. The authCallback you configured during the object instantiation will be triggered after the call either succeeds with an id_token or fails with an error.

You can see an example of using the MSAL.js in this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi-v2/blob/master/TodoSPA/App/Scripts/app.js#L49).

Answer (score 0):

The authCallBack is not called after a acquireSilentToken